# Who was in the room in the X-Men Mansion?

Tags: marvel, x-men, x-men-cinematic-universe, deadpool, deadpool-2

When Deadpool is in the hallway talking

> he makes a joke about Fox springing for a few more X-Men and the camera pans to show Beast closing the door to get rid of the noise.

Who else was in the room?

Answer (score 18):

While most sources seem to have caught a couple, [DigitalSpy seems to be confident](http://www.digitalspy.com/movies/deadpool/feature/a857059/deadpool-2-x-men-timeline-when-is-it-set/), from their wording, that they saw everyone. [Den of Geek's incredibly detailed commentary](http://www.denofgeek.com/us/movies/deadpool-2/273493/deadpool-2-complete-marvel-and-x-men-easter-eggs-and-comic-reference-guide) on Easter eggs gives the longest list of 6 characters:

- ### Nicholas Hoult's [Beast](http://xmenmovies.wikia.com/wiki/Beast)
- ### James McAvoy's [Charles Xavier](http://xmenmovies.wikia.com/wiki/Professor_X)
- ### Alexandra Shipp's [Storm](http://xmenmovies.wikia.com/wiki/Storm)
- ### Evan Peters' [Quicksilver](http://xmenmovies.wikia.com/wiki/Quicksilver)
- ### Tye Sheridan's [Cyclops](http://xmenmovies.wikia.com/wiki/Cyclops)
- ### Kodi Smit-McPhee's [Nightcrawler](http://xmenmovies.wikia.com/wiki/Nightcrawler)

This seems to be confirmed by the following still:

[image: Still from film]

This lineup seems to be a shout to the X-Men: Dark Phoenix characters and the current X-men team in the X-Men Cinematic Universe.

Comment: @StevenVascellaro not added because 1 wasn’t in the mansion, 2 wasn’t actually a cameo but just the footage from the old film, which I felt doesn’t count.

Comment: I believe [this](https://scontent-frt3-1.cdninstagram.com/vp/bcd1320d838e16cdaad4fa3549fd04b7/5C2FFD02/t51.2885-15/e35/39364468_273233489952135_8225259355667169280_n.jpg?se=8&ig_cache_key=MTg1MjY3Njc4NDUzODg5MTMyMg%3D%3D.2) is a still of the scene.